# Establish Units of Measure Relationships With a Quantity of Another Unit

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

I realize that you can express relationships with dimensions of units, like

```fs
[<Measure>] type cc = cm^3
```

and perform meaningful calculations later.

Given some unit of measure type,

```fs
[<Measure>] type m
```

Is it possible to define a unit in a relationship with a quantity of another unit? For example,

```fs
// doesn't compile
[<Measure>] type mm = 0.001<m>

// later
let length = 500.0<mm>
let length2 = 0.5<m>
printfn "%A" (length = length2) // prints true
```

Comment: Not an easy way but you can define say `mm` and `m` and then a type-safe conversion function.

Comment: Largely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822066/converting-from-m-s-to-km-h-using-f-units-of-measure Anyway, there will be no implied conversion. In comments, there are also some arguments about `kilo` (or `milli`) as a separate UoM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short: no.

Units of measure are annotations on primitives. Period. As you probably know, they will be *deleted* during compilation.

So here's their fundamental limitation: you cannot *attach* any kind of functionality to them, because they will all turn into plain old `float`s.

The compiler will check that your expressions are dimensionally valid, but (for now) it does not automatically generate or insert any sort of 'default' type-conversion functions.

You must write and use those functions yourself, and the best you can do is to make them as straightforward as possible.

Here's how I'd organise your example:

```
[<Measure>] type mm    
[<Measure>] type mt

// first, I like to define basic functions to quickly annotate dimensionless values
let mm = (*) 1.0<mm>
let mt = (*) 1.0<mt>

// we define a constant conversion
let MmPerMt = 1000.0<mm/mt>

// (though nothing forbids us from defining any conversion we want, and the compiler cannot privilege one over another)
let INeverPaidAttentionInGradeSchool = 12345<mm/mt>

// for ease of use, we bake the conversion constant into functions
let MtToMm = (*) MmPerMt

// usage
let someUserInputInMeters = "12414.23"

let desiredValueInMillimeters = someUserInputInMeters
                                |> float
                                |> mt
                                |> MtToMm
```